# Auto sharding postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning, sharding

I have a problem where I need to load alot of data (5+ billion rows) into a database very quickly (ideally less than an 30 min but quicker is better), and I was recently suggested to look into postgresql (I failed with mysql and was looking at hbase/cassandra). My setup is I have a cluster (currently 8 servers) that generates alot of data, and I was thinking of running databases locally on each machine in the cluster it writes quickly locally and then at the end (or throughout the data generating) data is merged together. The data is not in any order so I don't care which specific server its on (as long as its eventually there).

My questions are , is there any good tutorials or places to learn about PostgreSQL auto sharding (I found results of firms like sykpe doing auto sharding but no tutorials, I want to play with this myself)?  Is what I'm trying to do possible? Because the data is not in any order I was going to use auto-incrementing ID number, will that cause a conflict if data is merged (this is not a big issue anymore)?

Update: Frank's idea below kind of eliminated the auto-incrementing conflict issue I was asking about. The question is basically now, how can I learn about auto sharding and would it support distributed uploads of data to multiple servers?

Comment: I've loaded ~10 million rows into a postgres database in <5 min, so I can confidently tell you that this is a very important resource to lean on, when loading data into a single shard: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/populate.html  This also looks promising: http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/

Comment: `I was going to use auto-incrementing ID number, will that cause a conflict if data is merged?` Just increment by 10, and start at different offsets.  Server 1 uses ids 1,11,21,31; server 2 uses ids 2,12,22,32

Comment: @FrankFarmer Thanks for the link and the great idea re:incrementing.  I think that takes some of the complexity out, then I guess the question is only related to auto-sharding and distributed uploads.

Comment: Note that increments and offsets are trivially done with sequences: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 14):

First: Do you really need to insert the generated data from your cluster straight into a relational database? You don't mind merging it at the end anyway, so why bother inserting into a database at all? In your position I'd have your cluster nodes write flat files, probably gzip'd CSV data. I'd then bulk import and merge that data using a tool like [pg_bulkload](http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/).

If you do need to insert directly into a relational database: That's (part of) what [PgPool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/) and (especeially) [PgBouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/) are for. Configure PgBouncer to load-balance across different nodes and you should be pretty much sorted.

Note that PostgreSQL is a transactional database with strong data durability guarantees. That also means that if you use it in a simplistic way, doing lots of small writes can be slow. You have to consider what trade-offs you're willing to make between data durability, speed, and cost of hardware.

At one extreme, each `INSERT` can be its own transaction that's synchronously committed to disk before returning success. This limits the number of transactions per second to the number of fsync()s your disk subsystem can do, which is often only in the tens or hundreds per second (without battery backup RAID controller). This is the default if you do nothing special and if you don't wrap your `INSERT`s in a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

At the other extreme, you say "I really don't care if I lose *all* this data" and use [unlogged tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#AEN67434) for your inserts. This basically gives the database permission to throw your data away if it can't guarantee it's OK - say, after an OS crash, database crash, power loss, etc.

The middle ground is where you will probably want to be. This involves some combination of [asynchronous commit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-async-commit.html), [group commits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-configuration.html) ([commit_delay](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-COMMIT-DELAY) and [commit_siblings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-COMMIT-SIBLINGS)), batching inserts into groups wrapped in explicit `BEGIN` and `END`, etc. Instead of INSERT batching you could do `COPY` loads of a few thousand records at a time. All these things trade data durability off against speed.

For fast bulk inserts you should also consider inserting into tables without any indexes except a primary key. Maybe not even that. Create the indexes once your bulk inserts are done. This will be a hell of a lot faster.

Comment: Wow..thank you for the great answer.  Your right I don't need a database at all but I'm trying to use it to share the end data with other worker nodes.  So my first process generates alot of data but the second process uses a cluster to analyze the data against a previous dataset(generated same way just on a different day).  I'm not sure if I need the middle ground or the more extreme unlogged tables because if I only use data if the db dies then I'll know when it dies and can restart my processing again, but if it doesn't die and goes slow then I'll miss my deadline.

Comment: Do you think it makes more sense in my case to save the data as a file then and simply upload it?  I thought since I was going to have it in a database to analyze in the end I might as well create threads in my program that send it while I'm processing, but if its faster just to write locally and then bulk upload I might just do that..Also, I do not have any indexes on the table(my column is a dictionary of string/int that I'm loading as a string and the other is a ID column which I think will be a Long int..). All other decision considerations are just for speed.

Comment: The thing about inserting the data into a sharded database is that it's only useful if you can query it in its sharded form. There are tools for that (see, eg, PL/Proxy) but they're more complex and difficult to use than a single DB instance. OTOH, they can be a lot faster. If you're not going to be querying the shards but instead want to merge the data before analysing it, you might as well write it as flat files and just insert it into the final DB.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that might help:

- The DB on each server should have a small meta data table with that server's unique characteristics.  Such as which server it is; servers can be numbered sequentially.  Apart from the contents of that table, it's probably wise to try to keep the schema on each server as similar as possible.
- With billions of rows you'll want bigint ids (or UUID or the like).  With bigints, you could allocate a generous range for each server, and set its sequence up to use it.  E.g. server 1 gets 1..1000000000000000, server 2 gets 1000000000000001 to 2000000000000000 etc.
- If the data is simple data points (like a temperature reading from exactly 10 instruments every second) you might get efficiency gains by storing it in a table with columns `(time timestamp, values double precision[])` rather than the more correct `(time timestamp, instrument_id int, value double precision)`.  This is an explicit denormalisation in aid of efficiency.  (I [blogged](http://ejrh.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/vector-denormalisation-in-postgresql/) about my own experience with this scheme.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [citus](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/aboutcitus/what_is_citus.html#when-to-use-citus) for PostgreSQL auto sharding. Also [this link](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/11/30/sharding-your-database/) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have a tutorial at hand, but here's an outline of a possible solution:

- Load one eight of your data into a PG instance on each of the servers
- For optimum load speed, don't use inserts but the [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) method
- When the data is loaded, do not combine the eight databases into one. Instead, use [plProxy](http://plproxy.projects.postgresql.org/doc/faq.html) to launch a single statement to query all databases at once (or the right one to satisfy your query)

As already noted, keys might be an issue. Use non-overlapping sequences or uuids or sequence numbers with a string prefix, shouldn't be too hard to solve.

You should start with a COPY test on one of the servers and see how close to your 30-minute  goal you can get. If your data is not important and you have a recent Postgresql version, you can try using [unlogged tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) which should be a lot faster (but not crash-safe). Sounds like a fun project, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at plProxy..seems really interesting. I'll try it out and unlogged tables..

Answer (score -1):

You could use mySQL - which supports auto-sharding across a cluster.

Comment: I believe you're thinking of MySQL Cluster, which is a paid product separate from MySQL itself.